# Admin user list custom column display based on custom user metadata in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, user-data

I have created a custom column for WordPress users called "Verification". Upon WooCommerce registration, an email is sent to the user asking them to verify their email and that way, account. This information is stored in the database under `usermeta (wp_usermeta)` as a meta_key and that key is called `is_activated`.

[image]

Here is the code for the custom column:

```
add_action('manage_users_columns','account_verification_status_column');
function account_verification_status_column($column_headers) {
  unset($column_headers['posts']);
  $column_headers['account_verification'] = 'Verification Status';
  return $column_headers;
}

function make_verification_status_column_sortable( $columns ) {
    $columns['account_verification'] = 'Verification Status';
    return $columns;
}
add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'make_verification_status_column_sortable' );
```

I am now trying to figure out how to fetch data from the usermeta table and in this case, the `meta_key` `is_activated`. Here is what I tried:

```
add_action('manage_users_custom_column', 'account_verification_information', 10, 3);
function account_verification_information($status = '1') {

    global $wpdb;
    $has_user_verified = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->users
        LEFT JOIN $wpdb->usermeta ON $wpdb->users.ID = $wpdb->usermeta.user_id
        WHERE meta_key = 'is_activated'
        AND meta_value = '$status';"
    , $level ));

    return $has_user_verified;
    $check_verification = account_verification_information(1);

  if ( $column_name === account_verification ) {
            echo $check_verification;
            } else {
                echo '<span class="na">Not yet Verified</span>';
            }
    }
```

Hopefully, by looking at it, you "get the idea".
I need it to show "Verified" if the value is 1 and "Not Verified" if the value is 0.

I've tried so many different versions of this I am getting lost..

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead:

```
add_action('manage_users_columns','account_verification_status_column');
function account_verification_status_column($column_headers) {
    unset($column_headers['posts']);

    $column_headers['account_verification'] = __('Verification Status');

    return $column_headers;
}

add_filter( 'manage_users_sortable_columns', 'make_verification_status_column_sortable' );
function make_verification_status_column_sortable( $vars ) {
    $columns['account_verification'] = 'account_verification';

    return $columns;
}

add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'add_user_column_value', 10, 3);
function add_user_column_value( $value, $column_name, $user_id ){
    if ( 'account_verification' == $column_name ){
        if( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'is_activated', true ) == 1 ){
            $value = '<span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Verified</span>';
        } else {
            $value = '<span class="na" style="color:grey;"><em>Not Verified</em></span>';
        }
    }

    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Comment: how would I do the same but for echo a value (text)?
I've added the column using the same code as above from you, but cannot figure out how to get the text (value) from billing_vatnr.

So, instead of is_activated, the field is called billing_vatnr and the output from that field is text and numbers (the company's VAT nr).

Any ideas?

Comment: @bjornen Try to use `if( $billing_vatnr = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_vatnr', true ) { echo $billing_vatnr; } else { echo "No value"; }` where `billing_vatnr` is a defined meta key with a defined meta value in user meta data *(so in `wp_usermeta` table for each customer)*

Comment: I added the modified version according to your example. The column is there but no data is shown, not even the "else" value. Maybe I did something wrong, but here is the code:

'code'add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'add_vatnr_value', 10, 3);
function add_vatnr_value( $value, $column_name, $user_id ){
    if ( 'account_vat' == $column_name ) {
        if ( $billing_vatnr = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_vatnr', true ) ) {
        echo $billing_vatnr;
        }
        else {
        echo "No value"; }
    }
    return $value;
}'code'

Any ideas?