# Display user meta data values in admin user list custom columns in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, user-data

For Woocommerce, with the help of [this answer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52677584/admin-user-list-custom-column-display-based-on-custom-user-metadata-in-wordpress/52678203?noredirect=1#comment92303706_52678203), I created some custom columns in Back end (Admin) user list:

[image]

In the database, there are some `meta_key` values called `billing_vatnr` and `billing_company` coming from the WooCommerce registration form and saved in `wp_usermeta` table.

[image]

What I'm trying to figure out is how to display the corresponding `meta_value` for those meta keys and show them in their respective column for each user.

In other words, in the **VAT Nr** field, the content of the meta key `billing_vatnr` should be displayed and if there is no content, display `N/A`. Same for Company Name column with `billing_company`.

This is what I've tried so far is:

```
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'vatnr_status_data', 10, 3);
function vatnr_status_data( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'account_vatnr' == $column_name ) {
        if( $billing_vatnr = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'billing_vatnr', true )) {
            echo $billing_vatnr; } else { echo "N/A"; }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Here are the different columns I've added:

```
// creating the columns
add_action('manage_users_columns','account_verification_status_and_company_columns');
function account_verification_status_and_company_columns($column_headers) {
    unset($column_headers['posts']);
    $column_headers['account_verification'] = __('Verification Status');
    $column_headers['account_vatnr'] = __('VAT Nr');
    $column_headers['account_companyname'] = __('Company Name');
    return $column_headers;
}


// fetching the verification status, thanks to LoicTheAztec
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'user_account_verification_status_data', 10, 3);
function user_account_verification_status_data( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'account_verification' == $column_name ) {
        if( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'is_activated', true ) == 1 ) {
            $value = '<span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Verified</span>';
        } else {
            $value = '<span class="na" style="color:grey;"><em>Not Verified</em></span>';
        }
    }
    return $value;
}
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: Nobody can help you on this if you dont show in your question the related code that display the `billing_vatnr` field and save the value in database…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I've updated with more information. Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following lightly revisited code with some additions for `account_vatnr` and `account_companyname` additional custom fields:

```
// Add custom columns to Admin users list
add_action('manage_users_columns', 'add_custom_users_columns', 10, 1 );
function add_custom_users_columns( $columns ) {
    unset($columns['posts']);

    $columns['account_verification'] = __('Verification Status');
    $columns['account_vatnr'] = __('VAT Nr');
    $columns['account_companyname'] = __('Company Name');

    return $columns;
}


// fetching the verification status, thanks to LoicTheAztec
add_filter('manage_users_custom_column',  'add_data_to_custom_users_columns', 10, 3);
function add_data_to_custom_users_columns( $value, $column_name, $user_id ) {
    if ( 'account_verification' == $column_name ) {
        if( get_user_meta( $user_id, 'is_activated', true ) == 1 ) {
            $value = '<span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">Verified</span>';
        } else {
            $value = '<span class="na" style="color:grey;"><em>Not Verified</em></span>';
        }
    } elseif( 'account_vatnr' == $column_name ) {
        if( $vat_nr = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_vatnr', true ) ) {
            $value = '<span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">' . $vat_nr . '</span>';
        } else {
            $value = '<span class="na" style="color:grey;"><em>N/a</em></span>';
        }
    } elseif( 'account_companyname' == $column_name ) {
        if( $company = get_user_meta( $user_id, 'account_companyname', true ) ) {
            $value = '<span style="color:green;font-weight:bold;">' . $company . '</span>';
        } else {
            $value = '<span class="na" style="color:grey;"><em>N/a</em></span>';
        }

    }
    return $value;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

---

From this registered data in `wp_usermeta` database table:

[image]

You will get the following display like in Admin users list for your custom columns:

[image]

Comment: thank you. Very kind of you to help. Thank you again.